# How to Add strings into each element of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

This is a rather basic question but as I am new to programming, I have been stuck on it for a little while. I am trying to add strings to the beginning and end of every element in a list (each element in the list is a string).

I know to use the StringJoin or <> function to join strings individually, e.g.:
"what I want to add"<>"original string"<>"what I want to add". However, I am having some trouble applying this broadly to each element in a list. I think I am supposed to use the Map or /@ function, but am simply lost at how to apply it correctly.

Here is an example:

> exampleList={"apple","pear","banana","orange"}

In the beginning of each element, I want to add the string: "Is this fruit a "
and in the end: "?"
so that the changed list would yield:

> exampleList={"Is this fruit a apple?", "Is this fruit a pear?", "Is
>   this fruit a banana?", "Is this fruit a orange?"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `StringTemplate["Is this fruit a ``?"] /@ {"apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"}`.

Comment: or, `StringForm["Is this fruit a ``?", #] & /@{"apple","pear","banana","orange"}` for version 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: @kglr that worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it producing better English:

```
Map[
 StringTemplate["Is this fruit `1` `2`?"] @@ 
   If[MemberQ[Characters["aeiou"], 
     StringTake[#, 1]], {"an", #}, {"a", #}] &, 
   {"apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"}]

(* {"Is this fruit an apple?", "Is this fruit a pear?", 
    "Is this fruit a banana?", "Is this fruit an orange?"} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ToString /@ StringForm["Is this fruit a ``?", #] & /@{"apple","pear","banana","orange"}
```

or

```
ToString /@ (Row[{"Is this fruit a ", "?"}, #] & /@ {"apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"})
```

to get

> {"Is this fruit a apple?", "Is this fruit a pear?", "Is this fruit a 
>   banana?", "Is this fruit a orange?"}

Comment: `ToString[]` will be needed if the OP wants actual strings.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. I updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
("is this " <> (StringMatchQ[#, Alternatives @@ Characters@"aeiou" ~~ __] /. {True ->"an "
<> #, False -> "a " <> #}) <> "?") & /@ exampleList

(*{"is this an apple?", "is this a pear?", "is this a banana?", "is this an orange?"}*)
```